# AJAX Nav doesn't work in Windows or Safari on Mac Or PC

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, menu

I have a menu that will be loaded via jQuery, but maintained as a separate html file, so as to be able to update it in one simple place, rather than on every page any time there's a change. The menu WAS working fine in every browser, then all of a sudden it stopped working in all browsers on Windows, and Safari on Mac or Windows. It only works in Chrome and FF on Mac, the rest it just populates the text, but the links are not active. I'm not sure if I have not declared the correct verison of jQuery in the head (or if I change to the latest, will it bust other things like I've seen in other situations) - I have 1.7 and 1.8 loaded. Where did I go wrong in my code or structure? Please advise, thanks.
Here is the page: http://devious.humanalbatross.com/ ( still in development, hence the 'devious' subdomain...and the pages that are linked will wrok because they are not menus with the jQuery populating it.

Here's my code:
 --This is where, the nav appears on any actual page

```
        <nav id="menu">
     <div class="clear"></div>
       </nav>
         <script type="text/javascript">
           $("#menu").load("main-nav.html");
         </script>
```

--This is the markup in the actual HTML file (main-nav.html) that the jQuery is pulling it from:

```
                                <ul class="mainmenu">
                                <li><a href="http://www.humanalbatross.com/sonica">Sonica</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://www.humanalbatross.com/wavywinds">Wavywinds</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://www.humanalbatross.com/staticmotion">StaticMotion</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://www.humanalbatross.com/porousmind">PorousMind</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://www.humanalbatross.com/contact">Speak To Me</a></li>
                                <div class="clear">
                                </div>
                            </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue has nothing to do with your javascript implementation but with your css.

Append the following styles to your style.css (line:101)

```
header {
   /* other styles */
   position: relative;
   z-index: 10;
}
```

This issues is caused by `section#homeContent` which margin is set to `margin: -100px 0 0 0;` and overlays your `header`. Take a look at the screenshot which outlines the problem.

My css changed the the default stack order of the element `header` by 10. So basically your header is now above your `homeContent`.

[image]

Comment: hey that works...but why? I will just have to readjust the positioning (i.e. - the margins and such because now it kicks it way up..but that's small patatos).
Many thanks!

Comment: hmm. z-index confuses me still, but I understand. I probably should stay away from weird margins and such, perhaps give it (the #homeContent) a specific height dimension and ensure that it's position determined by margin doesn't pull it over the nav. Or maybe I put a position on the container_24 (which is a class) somewhere that pulled it over. I really need to clean that mess of code up, I realize. Many thanks though!